# Pandas - How can I Improve execution time of a function in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function, performance, time

I'm actually performing some task in a pandas dataframe (+50k lines), but it's so slow.Actually is around 7 secs...

```
def check_uno(number,area):
    if number=='adm':
        if area==1:
            return 'uno-'+str(area)
        else:
            return area
    else:
        return area
    
%%timeit
df['area_uno']=df.apply(lambda row:check_uno(row['number'],row['area']),axis=1)
df
>>7.16 s ± 1.44 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Is there any way I can improve this time?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with `np.where`:

```
df['area'] = df['area'].astype(str)
df['area_uno'] = np.where(df['number'].eq('adm') & df['area'].eq("1"), 'uno-' + df['area'], df['area'])
```

`np.where` is much faster than `df.apply`, because NumPy is implemented in C... Comparing the speed of C and Python is comparing night and day...

Comment: Thanks! I've tried but I get this error: UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')

Comment: Hi, It worked!, I got 811 ms ± 55.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) Thanks!

Comment: @user9910379 That's much faster :)!

Comment: @user9910379 Mine is like 10 times faster :P

Comment: @U12-Forward actually you can go even faster if you convert to `df["area]` to string before `np.where`.

Comment: @user9910379 Please see what rpanai mentioned.

Comment: Awesome! Got 272 ms ± 14.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) Thanks a lot both U12-Forward & @rpanai ! You rock!

Comment: @user9910379 That's a 30 times faster code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), which enables you to perform vectorial comparisons:

```
df['area_uno'] = df.mask(df['number'].eq('adm')&df['area'].eq(1), # if both conditions
                         'uno-'+df['area'].astype(str) # replace with concatenation of "uno-" and area
                         )
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway!

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiprocessing for much faster runtime:

```
import pandas as pd
import concurrent.futures
import time

start_time = time.time()

def split_df_into_groups_of_fix_size(df, group_size):
    lst = [df.iloc[i:i + group_size] for i in range(0, len(df) - group_size + 1, group_size)]
    return lst


# number of rows to pass each process (like "batch_size of rows")
group_size = 1

# split df into groups of dataframes with "group_size" rows in each.
lst = split_df_into_groups_of_fix_size(df=df, group_size=group_size)
# number of processes
executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(20)
futures = [executor.submit(check_uno, group)
           for group in lst]
concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

# concatenate results into one dataframe
result_concat = pd.concat([res.result() for res in futures if res.result() is not None])
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Thank you @nivdudovitch!